# jQuery spawn boxes and give css styling afterwards

Tags: jquery, css, delay

I'm trying to make it rain cookies on my site.
My problem is that the cookies spawn with a margin 50% and not at 0 and then get a margin 50 as it should be.
I've found out that that "alert();" will make it work, but as you know, a box appears every time.
So the question is, is there a way to make a delay or something to make it work?

This is my code:

```
i = 1;

function spawnCookies(){

    /*setInterval(function()
        {

            var min = 10;
            var max = 60;

            var margin = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

        }, 100);*/

    setInterval(function()
        {

            bodyWidth = $(window).width();

            pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth) + 0;

            var minWidth = 10;
            var maxWidth = 60;

            var width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxWidth - minWidth + 1)) + minWidth;

            thisDiv = $(".cookieArea").append("<div class='cookie "+i+"' style='width:"+width+"px; height:"+width+"px'></div>");   

            $('.'+i+'').css('left',+pos+'px');

            alert();

            $('.'+i+'').css('margin-top','50%');

            i++;

        }, 800);

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    spawnCookies()

},4000);
```

Comment: Create an example at www.jsfiddle.net please

Answer (score 0):

Add the styling to a stylesheet instead, and then have a prefix on the class

Javascript, add this class instead:

```
$('.cookie' + i);
```

CSS add this:

```
[class^=cookie]{margin-top: 0;}
```

The cookie class will now spawn with margin-top 0, and if you change it in javascript later it should animate (if you use animation)